# Send location updates to firebase every 5 seconds?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I wanted to know what is the most **battery efficient** way to send **accurate** location updates to server/firebase every 5 seconds, even if app is closed or phone is rebooted. I tried using AlarmManager.setRepeating along with android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED receiver-

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                      SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                      5*1000, // 60000 = 1 minute,
                      pendingIntent);
```

But this doesn't work on Android 5.1+ due to -

> Frequent alarms are bad for battery life. As of API 22, the
>   AlarmManager will override near-future and high-frequency alarm
>   requests, delaying the alarm at least 5 seconds into the future and
>   ensuring that the repeat interval is at least 60 seconds.

Using post a delayed message or runnable to a Handler is not a reliable solution because as soon as application is swiped off location updates are stopped.

Is there any reliable way to send accurate location updates to server every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly (if you haven't already) - check out Google's [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) which is designed to be network/battery efficient when it comes to location updates.

Also, have you looked in to [GCM Network manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager)? This was designed to allow for battery efficient tasks (either one-off or recurring). It tries to batch those tasks them with other network requests to save multiple activiations of the device's radio. ([Here's a short explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ecz5WDZoJok))